# What is the purpose of the "Collection Reminder Send Flag" tab in CiviContribute?

Tags: civicontribute

I see a "Collection Reminder Send Flag" tab in CiviContribute when capturing a new contribution.
What is the purpose of this tab and why can't I select any of the options?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a custom field and in its configuration you have the "View only" checkbox checked. You probably also have or had some custom code that sends out reminders and then sets the value of the field.

It is probably from https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.manualdirectdebit

Comment: ie a custom field which an Extension on your site might have created